# ActionBar menu item background using xml drawable?

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, styles, menuitem

I was searching for a way to style the menu buttons in my ActionBar, I would like to use a .xml drawable with rounded corners as a background for my menu items (the item is basically a counter with numbers, which I update dynamically).

There is no documentation about adding a background drawable to menu items on the action bar. Can this be achieved??
Thanks!

Comment: So you are just changing the title of the item when you want to change the number?

Comment: @Karakuri - I need to add a drawable as background to the text.

Comment: This might give you some inspiration: http://www.jmhend.me/layerdrawable-menuitems

Answer (score 0):

Please see in [ActionProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionProvider) side